# What is a valid XHTML replacement for <span> to style text inside a form?

Tags: css

I've a need of span within a form... but it doesn't validate, so I need a better substitute.

So, I've:

[1 text field] [some text] [2 text field] [submit btn]

When I use span for [some text], all is good as it's an inline object everything aligns perfectly. But when I try to use div with display:inline alignment goes crazy.

I don't want to mess with floats. Is there a simple substitute for span inside form?

Comment: Why do you need to replace the `span` element in the first place? And can you setup a http://jsfiddle.net of your issue?

Comment: span is invalid xhtml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<label>
```

is the right tag to put in in a form, if you want to describe what the user should write in the field. It's an inline html element.

Comment: Nice! thanks... I forgot about it, I was trying to use <legend>, I didin't code long time and I'm forgetting it.